# Word for "person who unsuccessfully tries to be witty"

Tags: single-word-requests

I remember reading a very specific word defined as "someone who tries to employ wit unsuccessfully".  I have not been able to relocate where I read this and my research has been mostly dead-ends thus far.

This is not what I'm looking for: [What is a word for someone who tries to be clever?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/252215/what-is-a-word-for-someone-who-tries-to-be-clever)

Comment: To jog memories, do you recall if the word is formal, technical, slang, based on Latin, based on Anglo-Saxon etc?  Also is it new or old, Urban Dictionary or Shakespeare?

Comment: I think *you* should employ wit to describe the bon no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Witling* may be what you're looking for. See [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/witling) for a definition as "a would-be wit"

Comment: That may well be the correct answer. It does however suffer from the disadvantage of being archaic. Here's the Google ngram https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=witling&year_start=1670&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwitling%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Ouch! We better get the word out, literally!

Comment: We're witling away at it.

Comment: Hm. This is a good substitute, but I wouldn't consider this an actual answer, based off of Webster's or OED. It implies that the person is either witless, trying to be witty, or considers themselves witty.

Comment: Witling is it!  Thanks @Silenus.  I had no idea it was so archaic.

Answer (score 2):

**Lame** works, although I'm sure classy people use classier terms.

Answer (score 2):

The adjective *[ham-fisted](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ham-fisted)* and its brother *ham-handed* can be applied to bungled attempts in general, and are often applied to humor, i.e. ham-handed delivery, or a "[ham-fisted entertainer who's in on the joke](http://www.theguardian.com/stage/2015/jul/15/alex-edelman-steve-martin-edinburgh-fringe)."

Answer (score 0):

The death of the party.

Humor impaired.

Pathologically unfunny.

A comedic train wreck.

Answer (score -1):

Slang phrase: "clever dick" but I cannot think of one word. Sorry.